# XCode: Can't find iPhone OS that I just downloaded

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, emulation, ios14

I downloaded the iOS 14.7.1 runtime from [this site](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport) and put it in the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/` directory as the doc says. I re-started Xcode and went to `Xcode` -> `Preferences` -> `Components` and it shows all the available runtimes, but the 14.7.1 I just downloaded isn't there. Is there something I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to get iOS 14.6-14.8 to show up in that menu.

Comment: @Bbrk24 Do you know if there's another way to get an emulator to use those versions then?

Comment: Have you tried going to “Window” - “Devices” - “Simulators” and see if the OS version might be available to you when creating a new simulator?

Comment: @Rob Yes, I've tried that and when creating a new simulator it allows me to select `Device Type` (I select iPhone 7) and `OS Version`, which has only the two OS's that I've installed (14.5 and 15.2) and allows me to click `Download more simulator runtimes`, which takes me to the same list from the picture in my original post, which does not include the new 14.7.1

Comment: Finally got back to my computer. I’m seeing the same behavior as you, that iOS 14.7.x is neither available on the “components” screen nor as an option when creating a new device in the “devices” window. I even tried a few different Xcode versions from 13.0, 13.2, etc., all the way through 13.3.1.